# Using IF output as a variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have a table `alpha` has 3 column which `id (INT)` and `time1, time2 (DATETIME)`

Now I want to count how many rows in every day from `2017-04-18` to `2017-05-24` and I tried this query but failed

```
SELECT IF(time1 < time2, time2, time1) AS d, COUNT(DATE(d)) FROM alpha 
WHERE time1 IS NOT NULL AND time2 IS NOT NULL
AND DATE(d) BETWEEN DATE('2017-04-18') AND DATE('2017-05-24')
```

Data

```
ID  TIME1                  TIME2
-----------------------------------------------
1, '2017-04-19 04:08:03', '2017-04-19 04:08:03'
2, '2017-04-19 04:08:03', '2017-05-19 04:08:03'
3, '2017-06-19 04:08:03', '2017-04-19 04:08:03'
4, '2017-06-19 04:08:03', '2017-06-20 04:08:03'
5, '2017-05-19 04:08:03', '2017-05-01 04:08:03'
```

Expected result

```
DAY         COUNT
---------------------
2017-04-19  1
2017-05-19  2
```

Comment: Can you also share with us some sample data and expected result set?

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions#lag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
  SELECT DATE(d), COUNT(DATE(d)) FROM (
    SELECT IF(time1 < time2, time2, time1) AS d FROM alpha 
    WHERE time1 IS NOT NULL AND time2 IS NOT NULL
  ) AS t
  WHERE DATE(d) BETWEEN DATE('2017-04-18') AND DATE('2017-05-24')
  GROUP BY DATE(d);
```

OR which I don't like:

```
SELECT IF(time1 < time2, time2, time1) AS d, COUNT(DATE(IF(time1 < time2, time2, time1))) FROM alpha 
WHERE time1 IS NOT NULL AND time2 IS NOT NULL
AND DATE(IF(time1 < time2, time2, time1)) BETWEEN DATE('2017-05-13') AND DATE('2017-05-15')
GROUP BY DATE(IF(time1 < time2, time2, time1));
```